# Alternative to branch reset groups in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
> ';x=1024;y=768'.match(/^(?:;x=(?<x>.+?)|;y=(?<y>.+?))*$/)
[
  ';x=1024;y=768',
  undefined,
  '768',
  index: 0,
  input: ';x=1024;y=768',
  groups: [Object: null prototype] { x: undefined, y: '768' }
]
```

This regex only captures `y`. I want to capture both `x` and `y`. The source string can contain optional parameters in any order. i.e.

- `';x=1024;y=768'.match(REGEX)` should produce groups: `{x: '1024', y: '768'}`
- `';y=768;x=1024'.match(REGEX)` should produce groups: `{x: '1024', y: '768'}`
- `';y=768'.match(REGEX)` should produce groups: `{y: '768'}` (optionally `x: undefined`)

Is there any way to accomplish this with JavaScript's regex engine or do I have to resort to old fashioned parsing?

No need to assume digits. These are generic key-value pairs.

Comment: Splitting by `;` and turning the result into an object would probably be more readable and dynamic

Comment: @CertainPerformance This is part of a larger regex. If the only way is to pull out that piece and parse it separately then I'll do it that way, but I was hoping I could match it in one shot.

Comment: You seem to be looking for a repeated capturing group feature, not  a branch reset group. Since the group values are rewritten each time you should just 1) validate the whole string and if it is valid, 2) extract all matches.

Answer (score 1):

You should be just fine with this `^;x=(?<x>\d+)|;y=(?<y>\d+)$` as long as you have the [`g`](https://javascript.info/regexp-introduction#flags) flag set.
And if they're not always digits, change `\d` to some other predetermined group of characters you know will work.

Comment: Hmm... maybe if I merge all the match groups? `Array.from(';x=100;y=1024'.matchAll(/^;x=(?<x>\d+)|;y=(?<y>\d+)$/g))`

Answer (score 1):

Could clean the data first to get it into an easier to work with format:

```
';x=1024;y=768' // our original string
.replace(/^(;y=[^;]*)(;x=[^;]*)$/,'$2$1') // make sure x comes before y
.replace(/^(;y=[^;]*)$/,';x=$1') // add x before y if we have only a y
.replace(/^(;x=[^;]*)$/,'$1;y=') // add y after x if we have only an x
.match(/^(?:;x=(?<x>[^;]+)?;y=(?<y>[^;]+)?)$/) // extract x and y
```

Yes, that is ugly...
Could also add all permutations to the regexp to clean it, then parse it:

```
';x=1024;y=768' // our original string
.replace(/^(?:;x=(?<x1>[^;]+)?;y=(?<y1>[^;]+)?|;y=(?<y2>[^;]+)?;x=(?<x2>[^;]+)?|;x=(?<x3>[^;]+)?|;y=(?<y3>[^;]+)?)$/,';x=$<x1>$<x2>$<x3>;y=$<y1>$<y2>$<y3>')  
.match(/^(?:;x=(?<x>[^;]+)?;y=(?<y>[^;]+)?)$/) // extract x and y
```

Still ugly... and it doesn't get any better even with the help of look-arounds due to inconsistent ordering...

Unless, we went with the cleanest solution, and that's probably what the user "0x464e" was proposing with the `g` flag, in combination with your idea with matchAll and then just join everything together. Can also use semicolons for the delimiter `[^;]*` so we're not limiting ourselves too much regarding potential values:

```
Array.from(';x=1027;y=123'
.matchAll(/(?:^)?;x=(?<x>[^;]*)(?:$)?|(?:^)?;y=(?<y>[^;]*)(?:$)?/g))
.reduce(function(a,b){
  if(b.groups['x'] !== undefined){ a.x=b.groups['x']; }
  if(b.groups['y'] !== undefined){ a.y=b.groups['y']; }
  return a;
  },{x:undefined,y:undefined});
```

The `^` and `$` logic can probably be omitted, depending on how you want to handle invalid syntax...

Comment: Sorting is an interesting idea. I could normalize the source string and then attempt to match it. Not sure if that's actually quicker than just pulling it out and parsing it, but it's viable :-)

Answer (score 0):

This might be help you,though i am not expert in `regx`

```js
function getV(str){
 let resultArr = str.match(/(?:[^-a-zA-Z](x|y)=\w+)/gi);
 let group = {x:'',y:''};
 resultArr.forEach(item =>
  {
    let occ = item.split('=');
    if(occ[0].replace(/x/i,'x').includes('x')){
       group.x=occ[1]
    }else if(occ[0].replace(/y/i,'y').includes('y')){
      group.y=occ[1]
    }
  }
 )
 Object.keys(group).forEach((key)=> group[key] = group[key] == '' ? undefined :  group[key] );

 return group;
}

str1 = "';X=1024pX;df-x=320;dfZx=320;'"
str2 = "';x=1024px;y=320;df-x=320;dfZx=320;'"

console.log(getV(str1));

console.log(getV(str2));
```

Comment: That's a strange regex. You've discarded the capture groups and you've enforced 2+ digits (`[0-9]\d+`) not that I asked for digits :-) Plus I'd have to parse this after the fact, which falls under "old fashioned parsing".

Comment: I think there's a cleaner way to write that then using `.includes` but yeah, I can match the whole block and then parse it. That's what I ended up doing :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you want to do this:

```js
function propEqVal(string){
  var m = string.match(/[a-z0-9\/,.!@#$%\\\^&*()+?\s\-]+/gi);
  if(m){
    for(var i=0,n=1,o={},l=m.length; i<l; i+=2,n+=2){
      q = m[n].trim();
      if(!isNaN(q))q = parseFloat(q);
      o[m[i].trim()] = q;
    }
    return o;
  }
  return false;
}
console.log(propEqVal('a  = just a test. more (a-z0-9/,.!@#$%\\^&*()+?\s\-); x=1024;y=768'));
```

Comment: The variable name is important.

Comment: See the Object now. Notice that I cast those Strings to Numbers.

Comment: Still making too many assumptions. The exact format is `;<paramName>=<value>` where `<paramName>` comes from a fixed set of strings (in this case `x` or `y`, `foo` should not match), and `<value>` can be any character, not just numbers.